# how to change the date for only some specific rows based on time in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, time

I have a dataframe which looks like this :

```
    Date        Train        Station        Time        ID

0  02.10.2020   Flixtrain    London         10:40       1
1  02.10.2020   Flixtrain    Berlin         20:30       1
2  02.10.2020   Flixtrain    Hamburg        23:45       1
3  02.10.2020   VSOE         Amesterdam     21:30       2
4  02.10.2020   VSOE         Cologne        00:50       2
5  02.10.2020   VSOE         Berlin         04:30       2
6  02.10.2020   ICE-220      Warschau       12:35       3
7  02.10.2020   ICE-220      Breslau        17:40       3
8  02.10.2020   ICE-220      Prag           23:13       3
9  02.10.2020   ICE-342      Wien           00:35       4
7  02.10.2020   ICE-342      Salzburg       07:42       4
8  02.10.2020   ICE-342      Munich         13:13       4
```

What I want to do is to change the date where the time passes 24:00, but only for those rows with the same value in "ID" and "Train". The date for the rows after should remain the same.

what I expect is this :

```
    Date        Train        Station        Time        ID

0  02.10.2020   Flixtrain    London         10:40       1
1  02.10.2020   Flixtrain    Berlin         20:30       1
2  02.10.2020   Flixtrain    Hamburg        23:45       1
3  02.10.2020   VSOE         Amesterdam     21:30       2
4  03.10.2020   VSOE         Cologne        00:50       2
5  03.10.2020   VSOE         Berlin         04:30       2
6  02.10.2020   ICE-220      Warschau       12:35       3
7  02.10.2020   ICE-220      Breslau        17:40       3
8  02.10.2020   ICE-220      Prag           23:13       3
9  02.10.2020   ICE-342      Wien           00:35       4
7  02.10.2020   ICE-342      Salzburg       07:42       4
8  02.10.2020   ICE-342      Munich         13:13       4
```

Is it possible to do that?Any help will be appreciated.
Many thanks

Comment: Your example is not consistent with your text: you expect to change the date on rows 4 and 5, but on those rows ID=2 and Train=VSOE, they don't have the same value.

Comment: @joao the rows 4 and 5 have the same ID, which is 2, and same Train, which is VSOE. I don't understand your point. :)

Comment: I see, I thought you meant the same values inside the same row. I still have trouble understanding your specification: the last 3 rows share the same values of Train and ID, yet you didn't change the date?

Comment: yeah because they don't meet the condition. So it time should pass the 12 pm (24:00). But the last three rows it starts at 00:35 and ends at 13:13, which means it happened at the same day and there no need for date change

Comment: ok, now I get it, we need to first conceptually **group** the rows that match ID and Train, and then check the time condition on the whole group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a new column named `t` to maintain the `timedelta` between `first occurence of each group` and its values.
`cond` is the condition which will consider `1 day of delta` for each group, if in your dataset there are more than one days of difference in each group then just modify the `cond` accordingly.

```
df['t'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Time, format='%H:%M')
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, dayfirst=True)

cond = df.groupby(['Train','ID']
                 ).t.transform('first') - df.groupby(
    ['Train','ID']).t.transform(
          lambda x: x.values) > pd.Timedelta('0 days')

df.Date = df.Date.mask(cond,df.Date + pd.Timedelta(days=1))
df = df.drop('t',1)
df
```

**Output**

```
    Date        Train       Station     Time    ID
0   2020-10-02  Flixtrain   London      10:40   1
1   2020-10-02  Flixtrain   Berlin      20:30   1
2   2020-10-02  Flixtrain   Hamburg     23:45   1
3   2020-10-02  VSOE        Amesterdam  21:30   2
4   2020-10-03  VSOE        Cologne     00:50   2
5   2020-10-03  VSOE        Berlin      04:30   2
6   2020-10-02  ICE-220     Warschau    12:35   3
7   2020-10-02  ICE-220     Breslau     17:40   3
8   2020-10-02  ICE-220     Prag        23:13   3
9   2020-10-02  ICE-342     Wien        00:35   4
10  2020-10-02  ICE-342     Salzburg    07:42   4
11  2020-10-02  ICE-342     Munich      13:13   4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start with creating an array to determine if date should increment.
lets say  we name it "registered" . Then you can concatenate the name of the train and the ID to check if the date should increment.

```html
registered = [] 


def register( train, ID  ) :

    reg = concat( train , ID )
    registered.append( reg  )

def concat ( train , id )
    return train + str(ID)  )

def isRegistered( string   ) : 
    if string in registered : 
        return True 
    return False 

#your DataFrame name let's suppuse df 
df 
count = -1 
for train in df["Train" ] : 
    count = count + 1 

    ID = df["ID"][ count ] 
    date = df["Date" ][count] 
    

    if isRegistered( concat( train , ID ) )  == True  :
        date = date + 1 
        # you may need to convert date object to incremet the day ()
        #increment(date )
    

    register( train , ID  )
```